# Joining 2 tables fill 0

Tags: mysql

I have problems displaying a table that combines two tables like this:

----------Size S----Size M----Size XL

AShirt----  15-------- 2 -------- 0

BShirt----- 2 --------- 12-------- 3

There's a shirt Table with the quantities (NO entry when it's 0 of a specific size). 
And there's a table with all sizes.

How can I get a set of data that also would display Ashirt - Xl - "0" I Don't know how to join them.

More general: How to join two tables, and if there's no match, set the missing fields = 0 instead of leaving out that record.

Comment: Please show table structure and sample data.

Comment: ... and the desired output result